# get value of multiselect struts2 from action class

Tags: jsp, struts2

I am trying to retrieve the multiselect value from action class. I did like that and getting null for cat Object from action class.

```
<s:select key="cat" id="cat_multi" name="cat" listKey="catID"
            list="catList" listValue="catName" multiple="multiple" size="5" />


public String getCat() {
        return cat;
    }


    public void setCat(String cat) {
        this.cat = cat;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the correct usage of `multiple` attribute is `multiple="true"`. Second: in order to work multiple select needs `multiselect` interceptor to be included in your interceptors stack.

Just use `defaultStack` in your `struts.xml` and your `<s:select>` declaration should look like that.

```
<s:select key="cat" id="cat_multi" name="cat" listKey="catID"
        list="catList" listValue="catName" multiple="true" size="5" />
```

Comment: can you provide me some helpful reference link (such as a good example  of how to use)?